# How to set an API key when using Google's script loader?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-ajax-api, google-loader

I registered my project and generated a browser key at https://code.google.com/apis/console/.

Now how do I use that key when using the [Google Script Loader](https://developers.google.com/loader/)?

I've been doing this, which works (with or without the key parameter), but even after several weeks the API console shows no requests:

```
<script src=//www.google.com/jsapi?key=my_key"></script>
<script>
    google.load('maps', '3.10', { other_params : 'libraries=places&sensor=false', callback : ... })
</script>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The key is useless for the jsapi, you must append it to `other_params`:

```
<script>
    google.load('maps', '3', {
        other_params: 'key=my_key',
        callback: function(){}
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using charts/loader you have to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages':['geochart'],
        // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
        // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
        'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);
    ...
</script>
```

Note the **mapsApiKey** property.

As described in https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart